Vertically center div inside another div that has no fixed height
In the code I'm trying to align the tail of the speechbubble with roughly the center of the image, regardless of the height of the speechbubble or the size of the image. Ideally I always want the image to be centered in what the current height of the wrapper is, the same as the tail of the speechbubble does to the height of the speechbubble itself.
However none of the attempts so far seemed to work. How can I achieve this?
I have the following code currently:


@text: black;
@bkg: white;
@accent: rgba(75, 75, 75);

.wrapper {
    padding: 2rem 0;
}

.wrapper, .wrapper * {
    white-space: pre-line;
}

.bubble {
    background: gray;
    min-height: 225px;
    padding:10px; 
    max-height:auto; 
    width: 60%;
    border-radius: 10px;
    color: black; 
      position: relative;
    text-align:center;
    display: table;
    
}

.bubble:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 50%;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border: 20px solid transparent;
    border-left-color: gray;
    border-right: 0;
    border-bottom: 0;
    margin-top: -10px;
    margin-right: -20px;
}

.bubble span {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.image {
    min-height:10px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    width: 35%;
}

.image img {
    max-width: 100%;
}
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="image">
    <img src="https://images.squidge.org/images/2024/04/09/biscuit_portrait.png" class="bbcode_image" loading="lazy">
  </div>
  <div class="bubble">
    <span style="font-size:10pt">
            elit enim in ex. Cras auctor lorem id lobortis feugiat. Maecenas egestas diam molestie ex tincidunt, eget tristique lectus sollicitudin. Aliquam quis risus facilisis nulla placerat ornare bibendum porta metus. Nulla placerat efficitur tincidunt. Nunc mattis neque non lectus interdum posuere. Curabitur id neque congue nibh condimentum molestie nec et mauris. Vivamus sed quam vitae leo varius sollicitudin et eget metus. Cras vestibulum ultrices viverra. Fusce accumsan scelerisque sapien, id pharetra massa sagittis eu. Nulla nec lectus accumsan, ultricies purus sagittis, consectetur lorem. Nam suscipit diam ac mauris ultricies rutrum. Sed auctor, augue eu porttitor suscipit, urna leo blandit ante, ac commodo ante augue ac odio. Vestibulum faucibus imperdiet purus, id gravida nisl rhoncus vitae. Etiam rhoncus dictum sem, nec imperdiet purus consectetur nec. Mauris sed mi scelerisque, consectetur quam a, malesuada orci.elit enim in ex. Cras auctor lorem id lobortis feugiat. Maecenas egestas diam molestie ex tincidunt, eget tristique lectus sollicitudin. Aliquam quis risus facilisis nulla placerat ornare bibendum porta metus. Nulla placerat efficitur tincidunt. Nunc mattis neque non lectus interdum posuere. Curabitur id neque congue nibh condimentum molestie nec et mauris. Vivamus sed quam vitae leo varius sollicitudin et eget metus. Cras vestibulum ultrices viverra. Fusce accumsan scelerisque sapien, id pharetra massa sagittis eu. Nulla nec lectus accumsan, ultricies purus sagittis, consectetur lorem. Nam suscipit diam ac mauris ultricies rutrum. Sed auctor, augue eu porttitor suscipit, urna leo blandit ante, ac commodo ante augue ac odio. Vestibulum faucibus imperdiet purus, id gravida nisl rhoncus vitae. Etiam rhoncus dictum sem, nec imperdiet purus consectetur nec. Mauris sed mi scelerisque, consectetur quam a, malesuada orci.

Nunc arcu justo, tincidunt sit amet augue et, consectetur vehicula enim. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Cras sed posuere metus. Cras feugiat, ex sit amet pretium vestibulum, neque quam fringilla augue, sed efficitur ligula quam non diam. Phasellus pellentesque euismod nunc sed mollis. Sed faucibus leo non eros bibendum, cursus gravida lacus scelerisque. Vivamus at congue felis, vitae aliquet leo. Duis at orci sed arcu condimentum suscipit. Vestibulum laoreet enim id metus ultrices aliquet eget a nunc. 
    </span>
  </div>
</div>




Instead of absolutely positioning the image, you should make the wrapper a flex container. Then you can align the items in it.

With position absolute and without fixed size it could not be done. The best option that comes to my mind is using display: flex and align-items: center on the wrapper and inverting the order of the image and the bubble on the HTML or using flex-direction: row-reverse on the wrapper too.


@text: black;
@bkg: white;
@accent: rgba(75, 75, 75);

.wrapper {
    padding: 2rem 0;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center
}

.wrapper, .wrapper * {
    white-space: pre-line;
}

.bubble {
    background: gray;
    min-height: 225px;
    padding:10px; 
    width: 60%;
    border-radius: 10px;
    color: black; 
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

.bubble:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 50%;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border: 20px solid transparent;
    border-left-color: gray;
    border-right: 0;
    border-bottom: 0;
    margin-top: -10px;
    margin-right: -20px;
}

.bubble p {
    font-size: .625rem;
    margin: 0;
}

.image {
    min-height:10px;
    right: 0;
    width: 35%;
}

.image img {
    max-width: 100%;
}
<div class="wrapper">

  <div class="bubble">
    <p>
            elit enim in ex. Cras auctor lorem id lobortis feugiat. Maecenas egestas diam molestie ex tincidunt, eget tristique lectus sollicitudin. Aliquam quis risus facilisis nulla placerat ornare bibendum porta metus. Nulla placerat efficitur tincidunt. Nunc mattis neque non lectus interdum posuere. Curabitur id neque congue nibh condimentum molestie nec et mauris. Vivamus sed quam vitae leo varius sollicitudin et eget metus. Cras vestibulum ultrices viverra. Fusce accumsan scelerisque sapien, id pharetra massa sagittis eu. Nulla nec lectus accumsan, ultricies purus sagittis, consectetur lorem. Nam suscipit diam ac mauris ultricies rutrum. Sed auctor, augue eu porttitor suscipit, urna leo blandit ante, ac commodo ante augue ac odio. Vestibulum faucibus imperdiet purus, id gravida nisl rhoncus vitae. Etiam rhoncus dictum sem, nec imperdiet purus consectetur nec. Mauris sed mi scelerisque, consectetur quam a, malesuada orci.elit enim in ex. Cras auctor lorem id lobortis feugiat. Maecenas egestas diam molestie ex tincidunt, eget tristique lectus sollicitudin. Aliquam quis risus facilisis nulla placerat ornare bibendum porta metus. Nulla placerat efficitur tincidunt. Nunc mattis neque non lectus interdum posuere. Curabitur id neque congue nibh condimentum molestie nec et mauris. Vivamus sed quam vitae leo varius sollicitudin et eget metus. Cras vestibulum ultrices viverra. Fusce accumsan scelerisque sapien, id pharetra massa sagittis eu. Nulla nec lectus accumsan, ultricies purus sagittis, consectetur lorem. Nam suscipit diam ac mauris ultricies rutrum. Sed auctor, augue eu porttitor suscipit, urna leo blandit ante, ac commodo ante augue ac odio. Vestibulum faucibus imperdiet purus, id gravida nisl rhoncus vitae. Etiam rhoncus dictum sem, nec imperdiet purus consectetur nec. Mauris sed mi scelerisque, consectetur quam a, malesuada orci.

Nunc arcu justo, tincidunt sit amet augue et, consectetur vehicula enim. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Cras sed posuere metus. Cras feugiat, ex sit amet pretium vestibulum, neque quam fringilla augue, sed efficitur ligula quam non diam. Phasellus pellentesque euismod nunc sed mollis. Sed faucibus leo non eros bibendum, cursus gravida lacus scelerisque. Vivamus at congue felis, vitae aliquet leo. Duis at orci sed arcu condimentum suscipit. Vestibulum laoreet enim id metus ultrices aliquet eget a nunc. 
    </p>
  </div>
    <div class="image">
    <img src="https://images.squidge.org/images/2024/04/09/biscuit_portrait.png" class="bbcode_image" loading="lazy">
  </div>
</div>



Also, I made some edits, to make it simpler. I recommend Flexbox and Grid and avoid using display: table and related properties because they are perfectly valid and still have their uses, Flexbox and Grid are more suited to general layout purposes in modern web design due to their flexibility, efficiency, and ease of use.
